# Access NSDictionary values

Tags: ios6, nsdictionary

I have a JSon object like this

{

```
Attendance =     {
    Attendance =         (
                    {
            EmployeeCode = 7593;
            InDate = "27/02/2013";
            InTime = "08:11";
            InTime2 = "00:00";
            OutDate = "27/02/2013";
            OutDate2 = "01/01/1901";
            OutTime = "17:42";
            OutTime2 = "00:00";
            Present = 1;
        }
    );
    AttendanceCount = 1;
};
AuthPersons =     {
    WFAuthCount = 1;
    WfAuthPersons =         (
                    {
            LsAuthls =                 (
                                    {
                    AuthEmployeeName = "SAMPLE NAME";
                    EmployeeCode = 4813;
                }
            );
            RequestTypeCode = 5;
            WFID = 99;
            "WF_LevelID" = 2;
            WorkFlowName = "EHL - Group HR (Kanchana/Asitha)";
        }
    );
};
```

}

What I wanted is to get these employeecode,IntDate... seperately So I get a seperate `NSDictionary` `NSDictionary *summary  = [resultJSON objectForKey:@"Attendance"];`

and return it into my `Viewcontroller method` inside my Viewcontroller I have done like this.

```
` nsDicttendanceReqDate = [[ws GetWorkflowInfoAttendanceRequest:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",usr.empCode] : @"5" :usr.stringRequestDate] copy];



 dicDates= [nsDicttendanceReqDate objectForKey:@"Attendance"] ;
//dicDates=[nsDicttendanceReqDatey JSONValue];

NSLog(@"%d",[dicDates count]);

NSLog(@"DIC DATES%@",dicDates);

NSLog(@"%@",nsDicttendanceReqDate);


 if ([nsDicttendanceReqDate count] > 0 ) {

    NSLog(@"TESTING---------- %@",[dicDates valueForKey:@"EmployeeCode"]);

    NSLog(@"TESTING---------- %@",[dicDates valueForKey:@"OutDate"] );

    NSLog(@"TESTING---------- %@",[dicDates valueForKey:@"InDate"] );`
```

But these are getting inside paranthesis. How can  I solve this.Any one can tell me how to extract this values.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.It might be a help.

NSDictionary *summary = [resultJSON valueForKey:@"Attendance"]objectAtIndex:0];